# Entity Framework lazy loading incorrect entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Consider the following (very simplified) entities:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string Text { get;set }
}

public class TeamMember
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }  
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

In my mapper I can set the User fine, but as soon as the following code is executed (before any changes are persisted in the DB)

`if (teamMembers.Select(x => x.User).Contains(currentUser))`

where teamMembers is a list of TeamMembers and currentUser  is a User entity loaded from the Db, then the User property of Answer is set to the previous value from the database. 
My understanding is that since I haven't accessed the User property of Answer before it hasn't been loaded from the database yet, and this is what happening (it's been lazy loaded?).

I could fix it by reading the User before even setting it in the mapper but what I cannot understand is why when I access the User property of TeamMember the User property of Answer is loaded and set? Is this expected behavior since both entities are associated with the same User (i.e. in the database they have the same User_Id as a foreign key) and when loading it for TeamMembers, EF tries to be clever and populate other entities that references it and haven't been loaded yet?

Answer (score 0):

The entities aren't stored/cached by the elements that have references to them but are stored with their own respective collections.

Once you loaded that User through the teamMembers reference, it was loaded... period. When you went to reference it from another element/object, it would be silly for it to go and load it again when it already has that object in memory.

This is all by design and it makes sense... if, for example, you wanted to save all these objects at the same time, it would first create the user, get an identity/key for it, then save the other objects that reference it with that key that was generated.

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#3

> "...the ObjectContext will check if an entity with the same key has
>   already been loaded into its ObjectStateManager. If an entity with the
>   same keys is already present EF will include it in the results of the
>   query. Although EF will still issue the query against the database,
>   this behavior can bypass much of the cost of materializing the entity
>   multiple times."

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't fully answer my question (probably wasn't clear enough). Let's say that I have two users, `User1 {}` and `User2 {}`. Could anyone explain why it it is that when I set the value of `answer.User` from `User1 {}` to `User2 {}` and then without saving run a select (eg, `teamMembers.Select(x => x.User).Contains(currentUser)`) on my teamMembers collection it is then resetting my answer’s User property back to `User1  {}`?

Comment: Has the User2 already been saved to the database, or is it only 'in memory' at that point?

Comment: I set the answer.User to User2 (which I retrieve from the database) but do not save this change yet if that's what you mean.

Comment: That seems pretty unusual. Are you *certain* this is the line where the answer.User changes. Did you set a Watch on answer and check it after each line? This, in no way, seems like something EF would (or even could) do.

Comment: It seemed pretty odd to me as well.... I set a breakpoint to the answer.User setter and it was hit straight after the `teamMembers.Select(x => x.User)`. The stack between the execution of that command and the setting of the user contained calls to EF methods (something to do with navigation properties if I remember correctly).

Comment: Your code doesn't show your mappings... the answer may lie there somewhere